# API request to update DE with compound primary key

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I'm trying to update DE containing compound primary key with this method

```
PUT /hub/v1/dataevents/key:{key}/rows/{primaryKeys}
```

[Documentation on method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/putDataExtensionRowByKey.htm)

which suggests adding primary keys as an array. Could you please advise on syntax of such request. I tried something like this:

```
key1:key_value&key2:key_value
```

But apparently, it is not the way to go. I also tried different methods with key included in the request body and it allows to insert records but I could not update them based on multiple keys I have. Any suggestions on different methods that could work would also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a comma to separate the keys.

```
key1:key_value,key2:key_value
```

Comment: Mike, thanks for the suggestion. It works! It tried it before but apparently, there also was a small mistake in the request body.